# Passing Stream to async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, async-await

I'm trying to pass a stream-parameter to an async method, like this:

```
async void MyAsyncMethod(Stream s, int i)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            SomeMethodReadingFromStream(s, i); // throws ArgumentException, "Stream was not readable."
        });
}
```

When I make MyAsyncMethod not use async-await, all works fine.

Is there a way to use a stream in an async method?

Comment: 1) Don't use `async void`

Comment: The stream was probably closed before your async code ran.

Comment: I believe you're disposing the stream outside the method. If yes don't do that.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`. If you really have to, use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The calling method probably looks like this:

```
using(var stream = ...)
{
    MyAsyncMethod(stream, 3);
}
```

Since you're kicking off `MyAsyncMethod` and then closing the stream, when `MyAsyncMethod` runs the stream will have been closed.

One way to solve this is to change `MyAsyncMethod` signature to return a task, and then await it.

```
async Task MyAsyncMethod(Stream s, int i) { ... }

using(var stream = ...)
{
    await MyAsyncMethod(stream, 3);
}
```

This way, the stream won't be closed until `MyAsyncMethod` is done.

Comment: Your assumption about the calling method is correct!